# Alt Gr turned into right mouse button, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse

For some reason my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key has begun to act as right mouse button. I've tried to look for similar symptoms for a few days, to no avail.

Using `evtest`, I've found out that *Macintosh mouse button emulation* is capturing the key:

Macintosh mouse button emulation:

```
Event: time 1435481009.075504, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 273 (BTN_RIGHT), value 1
Event: time 1435481009.075504, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1435481009.139420, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 273 (BTN_RIGHT), value 0
Event: time 1435481009.139420, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Keyboard is missing the EV_KEY:

```
Event: time 1435481097.155273, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e6
Event: time 1435481097.155273, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1435481097.219223, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e6
Event: time 1435481097.219223, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

I've tried to disable the button with `xinput`, which gets rid of the opening context menu, but doesn't help otherwise.

Same thing is happening both in console and under *Xorg*.

Few months ago I tried to get Revolution MX mouse buttons to work. This *might* have something to do with those changes.

I don't exactly remember what I did back then, but there's no `xorg.conf`, or any input mappings in the user directory any longer.

This isn't a problem with the keyboard. I've tried changing the hardware.

Comment: I set the Alternative Characters Key into Right Win for now, but still haven't been able to find a solution.

If I was able to disable the "Macintosh mouse button emulation", that would probably help. I suppose I could use udev rules to achieve that...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 fixed the problem. If someone knows a true solution, please post an actual answer.